# Issue in understanding Bootstrap Collapsible Hierarchy

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I want to create a dynamic Collapsible Hierarchy using Bootstrap and python Flask

Here is my code

```
<div class="list-group list-group-root well" style="width:60%">
   {% for majorversionname, majorversionId, minorList in [[1,1,[('1','1'),('1a','1a')]], [2,2,[('2','2'),('2a','2a')]] ] %}  
    <a href="#item-1-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Version - {{majorversionname}}
    </a>                                                               
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-1-1">                      
      {% for minorversionname, minorversionId in minorList%}
        <p >{{minorversionname}} </p>                                      
      {% endfor %}                     
    </div>                                                               
   {% endfor %}                                                     
</div>
```

My Output when I click Version-1 Button looks like this
 [Clicking Version-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTiSX.png)

This was expected. However when I click Version-2 link, I do not see Version-2 Lists instead I see the lists corresponding to version-1. Please check the below image

[Clicking Version-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VpXF.png)

So my question is where do I place the div and other elements so that when I click on Version-1 I see its lists and when I click Version-2 I see its lists.

I think we observe this behaviour as many copies of id="item-1-1" can not be possible. But without referring to the id. I can not make the Collapsible HIerarchy

Comment: I have tried all possible placements of div and the for loop, but to no avail. Has anyone figured out the answer yet?

Comment: I know it is causing due to the ID parameter id="item-1-1", but without it I can not make a proper reference.

Answer (score 0):

As I guessed it right, it is causing due to the ID field  id="item-1-1"
Changing it to id="#{{majorersionid}}", a dynamic id, resolves it!

```
<div class="list-group list-group-root well" style="width:60%">
   {% for majorversionname, majorversionId, minorList in [[1,1,[('1','1'),('1a','1a')]], [2,2,[('2','2'),('2a','2a')]] ] %}  
<a href="#{{majorversionId}}" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Version - {{majorversionname}}
</a>                                                               
<div class="list-group collapse" id="{{majorversionId}}">                      
  {% for minorversionname, minorversionId in minorList%}
    <p >{{minorversionname}} </p>                                      
  {% endfor %}                     
</div> {% endfor %}</div>
```